# Search and update on INSERT

Tags: mysql, join, insert-into

A client needs to migrate a large volume of data and I feel this question could be generic enough for SO.

**Legacy system**

Student profiles contain fields like names, emails etc, as well as university name. The university name is represented as a string and as such is repeated which is wasteful and slow.

**Our new form**

A more efficient solution is to have a table called `university` that only stores the university name once with a foreign key (`university_id`) and the HTML dropdown just POSTs the `university_id` to the server. This makes things much faster for doing `GROUP BY` queries, for example. New form data going into the database works fine.

**The problem**

How can we write a query that will INSERT all the other columns (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, ...) but then **rather than inserting the `university` string, find out its `university_id` from the `university` table and INSERT the corresponding int instead of the original string?** (scenario: data is in a CSV file that we will manipulate into INSERT INTO syntax)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a `LEFT JOIN`. Left is chosen so that student record won't get discarded if it has a null value for university_name.

```
INSERT INTO students_new(first_name, last_name, email, university_id)
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, s.email, u.university_id
FROM students_old s
LEFT JOIN university u ON s.university_name = u.university_name
```

Table and column names are to be replaced for real ones. Above assumes that your new table for students holding foreign key to university is `students_new` while the old one (from before normalisation) is `students_old`.

Comment: The migration was successful and the JOIN presented above worked flawlessly.